# Comma Seperated list formed from a dataframe breaks while passing into SQL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My query breaks when I dont have any values inside my dataframe.

I Have dataframe `data1['invoice_number']` which I am passing another sql as comma seperated list.

The below code works perfectly when we have values but breaks when I dont any value.

```
sql1 = '''selectcarrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
from invoice_summary where invoice_number in ({})'''.format(','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in data1['invoice_number']]))


inv_summary= pd.read_sql_query(sql1,cnx)
```

**Error**

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 2: from invoice_summary where invoice_number in ()
```

Is there a way I can still make this query execute without breaking.

Comment: why would you attempt to select when the df is empty?  It seems like you should be validating whether it is empty prior to running the query.  Perhaps look into exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow an empty list in `IN ()`. If you don't want to skip the query when the list is empty, what you can do is add an extra element to the SQL list that will never match.

```
sql1 = '''selectcarrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
from invoice_summary where invoice_number in ('', {})'''.format(','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in data1['invoice_number']]))
```